# wijmo wijtree child node re-ordering

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, wijmo

I am facing difficulty reordering the child node of wijtree. I used drag and drop feature to apply order. The drag and drop is not that much efficient. Sometimes it fails to drag the item in to right place. can anyone provide an efficient way to implement drag and drop feature and reorder using wijtree.

i have seen an example of third party js plugin which provides a drag and drop solution. I need a similar or better solution using wij tree.

Thanks much.

Here is the link of that third party plugin:
http://dragsort.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more on the exact error/issue you are facing on using drag n drop feature of WijTree. I tried the following demo and it works properly at my end:

http://wijmo.com/demo/explore/?widget=Tree&sample=Drag%20&%20Drop

Moreover, is there any specific browser in which this issue occurs ?

Regards